# Changing error 'cannot be blank' in Yii

Tags: php, error-handling, yii

Regarding handling error message in Yii: Commonly, Yii has configured form's validation, and when one of the required field isn't filled, then the error message will be shown as

```
"Blablabla cannot be blank."
```

How can I customize that error message? For example, I'd like to change into this:

```
"Blablabla tidak boleh kosong."
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its not clear what you are trying to do exactly, but

assuming you want to make a completely other message use :

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('title, content', 'required',
              'message'=>'Please enter a value for {attribute}.'),
        // ... other rules
    );
}
```

if you, on the other hand, are looking for translations, the best way to do it is by setting your language in the config

```
'language'=>'de',
'components'=>array(
    'coreMessages'=>array(
        'basePath'=>null,
    ),
        ......
),
```

if your language is not defined, copy framework/messages/en/yii.php to protected/messages/{yourlanguage}/yii.php and start translating, even if you wonna add messages, put the them in protected/messages/{yourlanguage}/ and never translate them in the framwork, so you can update without a fuss.

Comment: thanks to you, DarkMukke.. the 2nd solution really works on mine.. :D

Comment: no problem, you should look up 'yii internalization' : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you look for:

url: [Yii docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/1/how-to-customize-the-error-message-of-a-validation-rule/)

```
class Post extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('title, content', 'required',
                  'message'=>'Please enter a value for {attribute}.'),
            // ... other rules
        );
    }
}
```